# Google analytics Universal code not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal

I'm having a difficult time finding the error I may have commit with GA. I developed a site http://farmacia-milenium.com.ar that used the default universal tracking code. For some reason the script is not working and I'm not tracking correctly. I do not know if some code of the site may interrupt the code performance.

Could some one help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Assistant says the analytics.js script is not available and the console (in Google Chrome, that is) shows an error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

From that it would seem that your [content security policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) needs to be adapted to allow Google Analytics code to be injected into the page.

Comment: Hi Eike, I have check both. For some reason the CSP I have is not working.
I have implemented the following code on my htaccess

Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self';script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com; report-uri http://cspbuilder.info/report/5831563474954060414/"

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I could find the solution for my quest:

Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=631138519"
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header add Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; font-src data: 'self'; img-src data: http: 'self'; media-src *; object-src 'none'; script-src data: http: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; report-uri http://cspbuilder.info/report/**CODE**"