# Is it possible to get Google Adsense working without adding 'unsafe-inline' in content security policy (CSP)?

Tags: javascript, html, security, adsense, content-security-policy

I tried adding *nonce* to `SCRIPT_SRC`, but CSP complains about adsbygoogle.js:
refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

```
"script-src 'self' *.facebook.net *.facebook.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com 
google.com www.google-analytics.com adservice.google.com adservice.google.de 
pagead2.googlesyndication.com www.pagead2.googlesyndication.com 
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com storage.googleapis.com 
googleads.g.doubleclick.net ajax.googleapis.com 'nonce-5MallQacNWY+qLLMd5hwAGRaJXReVK7U'". 

(anonymous) @ adsbygoogle.js:2887
```

It complains about line 2887 (I unminified adsbygoogle.js to see which line   csp complains about).

I assume adding *nonce* will allow anything from the javascript file it is applied to, except `unsafe-inline`.

Is there another way to have google adsense play along with CSP or is adding 'unsafe-inline' the only option?

According to this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867210/4496068 it won't work properly with CSP.

Comment: its 2018 and, is there a solutions for this problem ?. google is very strict on security AFAIK but this is unacceptable. cant use their adsense or analytics without loosening the site security.

Comment: 2021 - the problem still exists! It is the pagead2.googlesyndication.com ads being built on the fly. It appears to possibly be the iframe with an onload trigger. So hard to track down though.

Comment: April 2021 still get these errors, so frustrating!