# Google Analytics/Google Ads and Content Security Policy

Tags: content-security-policy, google-analytics-4, react-helmet, google-ads-script, helmet.js

It's not easy to get Google Analytics/Google Ads working with CSP. I checked out a number of SO articles [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669075/can-content-security-policy-be-made-compatible-with-google-analytics-and-adsense), but wanted to see if there was another approach.

I found a pretty easy way to do it [in this article](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/07/20/using-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager-content-security-policy), and wanted to post it here in case it may be useful to others. I'll post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty easy way to do it [in this article](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/07/20/using-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager-content-security-policy):

> ...move the Google Analytics code snippet to an external code file,
> hosted on a domain that is already allowlisted by your script-src
> directed, such as the primary domain of your website.

The script originally supplied by Google was:

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-##########">
</script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-##########');
</script>
```

I went to `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-##########`, downloaded the script, and added this to the bottom of it:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-##########');
```

I saved it to my website. I added this:

```
<script async src="/script-saved-to-my-website.js"></script>
```

*...inside* the head section. (Google ads seems to want it inside the head section for some reason).

I added csp policy as described in the above article.

I connected Google Analytics 4 to Google Ads using the "connect to Google ads" feature I found in Google Analytics. Note: you have to have Google Ads in Expert mode, not Smart mode, for this to work.

I set up a Conversion goal on Google Ads.

And... it's working. :) I can see my stats on Google Analytics and my conversions on Google Ads.